# Alternative to software for Windows phone

Tags: 12.10, windows, phone

i just installed Ubuntu 12.10 LTS on my computer. However I have one problem. I use a Nokia Lumia 610 phone and therefore the OS is Windows Phone. In order to transfer songs, pictures etc. usually when using Windows I can use Zune software, however in Ubuntu this software doesn't work in Wine. When I connect the phone to a USB port on my computer, the computer detects the phone as a music device, but there are no files at all displayed

Is there any alternative for Zune in Ubuntu so that I can transfer songs, etc. to my cellphone?

Comment: when i connect the phone, the computer detect as music device but there is no files at all displayed

Comment: is MTP(Media transfer protocol) installed?WP connects to ubuntu through MTP

Comment: what is MTP? I never heard of such thing. Where can i download? How to install?

Answer (score 0):

you could try running zune through Wine, perhaps that will work.